# Throwing ResourceAccessException vs HttpClientErrorException for RestTemplate client in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, web

Using Spring 4.3.1 on Apache Tomcat 8.5, We have implemented a REST server that handles GET, POST & PUT requests. The POST request is handled in the form:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Transactional
public Response postMethod(final MyDomain object) {
     domainHandler.createDomain(object);
     return Response.status(201).entity(object).build();
}
```

During handling POST request on the server side, the WebApplicationException is thrown, which is handled by:

```
@Provider
public class WebExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException> {
     @Override
     public Response toResponse(WebApplicationException exception) {
          int httpStatus = exception.getResponse().getStatus();
          ErrorMessage em = new WebErrorMessage(exception.getMessage());
          return Response.status(httpStatus).entity(em).build();
     }
}
```

On the client side:

```
response = rest.exchange(requestURL, method, requestEntity, MyDomain.class);
```

the ResourceAccessException is thrown:

```
2017-07-25 15:46:41,489 ERROR [com.my.code.web.presentation.ManagementController:63] (http-nio-8080-exec-7#34): Internal exception occured with cause:
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8080/": Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/
     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:633) ~[spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580) ~[spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:498) ~[spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at com.my.code.web.integration.client.rest.FeedbackRestClient.callForApiCreateFeedback(FeedbackRestClient.java:218) ~[classes/:?]
     at com.my.code.web.integration.client.rest.FeedbackRestClient.pushFeedbackData(FeedbackRestClient.java:70) ~[classes/:?]
     at com.my.code.web.presentation.FeedbackController.feedback(FeedbackController.java:91) ~[classes/:?]
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor72.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [servlet-api.jar:?]
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [servlet-api.jar:?]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [catalina.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [catalina.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624) [catalina.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [catalina.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.16]
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.16]
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_131]
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_131]
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.16]
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8080/
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
     at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getBody(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at com.my.code.web.integration.client.rest.BufferingClientHttpResponseWrapper.getBody(BufferingClientHttpResponseWrapper.java:46) ~[classes/:?]
     at com.my.code.web.integration.client.rest.LoggingRequestInterceptor.traceResponse(LoggingRequestInterceptor.java:66) ~[classes/:?]
     at com.my.code.web.integration.client.rest.LoggingRequestInterceptor.intercept(LoggingRequestInterceptor.java:34) ~[classes/:?]
     at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69) ~[spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:619) ~[spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
     ... 47 more
```

> Question:

Why the exception `org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException` is thrown, but not `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException`, what's happening for handling the GET request when `WebApplicationException` occurs?

The `ResourceAccessException` exception does not have methods that allow me to read the HTTP status, eg `getRawStatusCode ()`, `getResponseHeaders()`, etc.

Comment: All the exception trace that you have posted are client side. The API is throwing 500 and the rest of exception mapping happens in the client context. Could you please try to add some additional logging in the server side - WebExceptionMapper to validate if the code block is getting executed?

Comment: Somethings really weird with your stacktrace: "Internal exception occured with cause: [...] Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL" in the catched one but "IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL [...]" in the cause. Is it really your stacktrace or you did a wrong copy/paste?

Comment: Your excange url is "http://localhost:8080/" and in your @POST request accept method haven't define this is default request acceptor like @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: This seems to be related: This seems to be related: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8713?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aworklog-tabpanel

Answer (score 4):

Because it's wrapping an `IOException`, not looking at the actual response code.

The root cause appears to be because `BufferingClientHttpResponseWrapper` is trying to read a body without checking if there is one first.

Comment: is there way to get httpStatus and responseBody?

Comment: @gstackoverflow what do you mean? There's a bug in `BufferingClientHttpResponseWrapper`, a class that the OP wrote.

Answer (score 1):

As Yasammez said in the comments, it is a [known, fixed bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8713?redirect=false&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%253Aworklog-tabpanel) that you get `ResourceAccessException` instead of a subclass of `RestClientException` such as `HttpClientErrorException` and has been fixed as of Spring 3.0.7.

The best I could do was catch both and only ask for the message, not the status code:

```
try {
    #method that calls restTemplate.getForObject(...) or similar
} catch (RestClientResponseException | ResourceAccessException e) {
    log.info("Failed to get remote resource because: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

You could also have 2 different catch statements and have one catch with a more verbose log if it gets there.