# ResourceAccessException received instead HttpServerErrorException

Tags: rest, microservices, spring-webclient

I have invoked rest Api in my microservice using RestTemplate. However incase of exceptions i have returned error data with HTTP response code as 500. But when i receive this response in my microservice , it is received as ResourceAccessException instead of HttpServerErrorException. Hence i lose the response body which i returned in my rest API. Spring web is of version 5.2.5

Answer (score 1):

Add below component

```
    

    import java.io.IOException;
    
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException;
    import org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException;
    import org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler;
    
    @Component
    public class RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {
    
        @Override
        public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
    
            return (httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == HttpStatus.Series.CLIENT_ERROR
                    || httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
    
            if (httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR) {
                    throw new HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
            } else if (httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == HttpStatus.Series.CLIENT_ERROR) {
                    throw new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        }
    }
```

And handle exception like below while calling API

```
ResponseEntity<Object> res = null;
try {
            res = restTemplate.exchange(completeUrl, HttpMethod.GET, null, Object.class);

            if (res.getStatusCodeValue() == HttpStatus.OK.value()) {
                
            }
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException e) {
            
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting this `ResourceAccessException` may be because you are using `BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory`. Without a full stack trace, I cannot be sure.
Look here for more details:
[Throwing ResourceAccessException vs HttpClientErrorException for RestTemplate client in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305811/throwing-resourceaccessexception-vs-httpclienterrorexception-for-resttemplate-cl)